# TestFlight rejects app because of binary file in upload

Tags: ios, sockets

I added SocketMoble ScanApiSDK to my app using CocoaPods and now when I try to upload it to TestFlight it shows that it is going to send libScanApiCore.a and after the upload I get an email from Apple that The binary file 'Express2.app/scanapisdk/lib/libScanApiCore.a' is not permitted. I find this file in the in the Pods/Development Pods/ScanAPI/Frameworks folder in my project. If I delete the file the it will not compile. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: `.a` files represent static libraries, they are indented to be linked against your executable, not deployed within the app bundle.

Comment: Do not include the static library in the final build. Go to your `Build Phases` and check that the `libScanApiCore.a` file is not included in the `Copy Bundle Resources` section.

Comment: The answer from quant24 allowed me to fix my problem. The ScanApiSDK folder was in the Copy Bundle Resources. When I deleted that I was able to send the app to TestFlight.

Comment: Glad to hear i could help.